# postgres: using function in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

the intention is to search across a few columns, get the sums of the weighted results, and return the top few of those. while the below statement runs as intended, it doesnt feel right having to explicitly use the same function over and over again, as a column, as the where criteria, and finally as order by. which is why this is incomplete, but i want to use all the similarity results to come up with a grand total simlarity, select where its above a certain level and order by that same value. but i need to spell it out for each action? is there a better way to write this?

```
    select parent.id, parent.name, child.id, child.name,
similarity(parent.name, $1) as parent_name_similarity, 
similarity(parent.abbreviated_name, $1) as parent_abbr_similarity, 
similarity(parent.common_name, $1) as parent_common_similarity, 
similarity(parent.state, $1) as parent_state_similarity, 
similarity(parent.city, $1) as parent_city_similarity ,
similarity(child.name, $1) as child_name_similarity,
(
    similarity(parent.name, $1)  
    + similarity(parent.common_name, $1)
    + CASE WHEN similarity(child.name, $1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE similarity(child.name, $1) END
) as weighted_total
from account_master parent 
left outer join child_table child on child.parent = parent.id::text
WHERE (
    similarity(parent.name, $1)  
    + similarity(parent.common_name, $1)
    + CASE WHEN similarity(child.name, $1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE similarity(child.name, $1) END
) > .3
ORDER BY (
    similarity(parent.name, $1)  
    + similarity(parent.common_name, $1)
    + CASE WHEN similarity(child.name, $1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE similarity(child.name, $1) END
) DESC;
```

update:
similarity is a built-in function that is like a text search, ie searching for the title of a book by only one word. it returns a percentage, 0 to 1, likelihood of result matching. so if a user is searching by company name or city name, i want to return whatever i have thats similar. they could search by name or initials, think fedex vs federal express. Or just Denver. Since im not sure which one they really want, i was going to add up the results across each field; name, common name, abbreviated name, city name, child thing name. So I have 6 individual column matches, i want to sum them into a single total, sort by that single total, and only return the top 5-10 of those when the total is above some threshold ~.3
So i end up calling the similarity function for each column, then also combine into the single total column, to combine again for the where clause, and to combine again for the order by

what i was hoping for was something like below where functions are needed once for columns only and alias can be used for sum, where and order

```
    select parent.id, parent.name, child.id, child.name,
similarity(parent.name, $1) as parent_name_similarity, 
similarity(parent.abbreviated_name, $1) as parent_abbr_similarity, 
similarity(parent.common_name, $1) as parent_common_similarity, 
similarity(parent.state, $1) as parent_state_similarity, 
similarity(parent.city, $1) as parent_city_similarity ,
similarity(child.name, $1) as child_name_similarity,
(
    parent_name_similarity  
    + parent_abbr_similarity 
    + CASE WHEN child_name_similarity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE child_name_similarity END
) as weighted_total
from account_master parent 
left outer join child_table child on child.parent = parent.id::text
WHERE weighted_total > .3
ORDER BY weighted_total DESC;
```

Comment: Please show the function and give an example of what $1 contains. How does that work? When called with a first parameter 'Mike' the function finds out somehow that this is about the name column, while 'New York' is considered to refer to the state column or the city column? Please also show sample data and the expected result.

Comment: You are using it with different parameters each time, perfectly fine.